# Scheduling an email in Salesforce Marketing Cloud with a Data Extension and exclusion Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions

I've scheduled an email to go out in a couple of days. It's going out to a Data Extension, which I'm good with. But I also have an exclusion data extension that will be suppressed.

Now this data extension that will be part of my exclusion/suppression, I have a daily import going into this exclusion data extension with an OVERWRITE rule.

So every day this exclusion data extension will overwrite with new data that will need to be excluded from my send.

Will my scheduled email reflect the latest import I have going on with that daily import that is going on in the background?

OR will the system only take a snapshot of what was in that exclusion data extension at the time of scheduling?

And I did all of this within a Guided Send.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you schedule an email in SFMC, the following process is done:

1. Email Content (HTML and AMPScript from all associated content areas or other assets) is stored in a 'snapshot' at time of schedule.
2. All associated Properties (subjectline, preheader, deliveryprofile, audience,etc.) are stored inside job 'snapshot' similar to content
3. Although the Sendable Data Extension or List ID (and corresponding suppression or exclusion lists/DEs) is stored in the snapshot, the actual data itself is not 'frozen' or locked in until the email actually enters the send queue.

What this means is that if you go to change the HTML on an already scheduled email, it will not be reflected in the send unless you cancel the previous send and then reschedule it.

BUT if you change the data in the sendable Data Extension (or associated exclusion data extension as in your case) this WILL be reflected up to the the time that the email is actually sent (the job begins). After the emails are processed/compiled and pushed to the send queue, then the data is locked in and nothing can be changed, only cancelled/paused.